# usb_modeswitch not working after after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, udev, usb-modeswitch

I have tested some usb-modems, mostly Huaweis. I got 2 of them working on 16.04 server fresh install, but they didn't autoswitch on 16.04 that was upgraded from 14.04.

In upgraded 16.04 server I get following error to usb_modeswitch.log:
Raw args from udev: 2-5_2-5:1.0
Bus ID for device not given by udev.
Top device directory not found (/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-5_2-5)! Exit.

Problem seems to be that usb_modeswitch is not able to define a rigth dir path from information given by udev. It tries to open 2-5_2-5, although rigth would be 2-5 and file starting 2-5 in that dir.

I tried to solve the problem through usb-modemswitch developers and got an answer that issue is a problem of the wrapper component of the Ubuntu fork:
[http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2627]

Anyone seen similar and any ideas how to fix this without coding and compiling files?

Is there a better forum to report and discuss Ubuntu sw problems?